# XCode: location simulator doesn't call locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:FromLocation

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, locationmanager

When I use the location simulator on XCode and change the location, it doesn't call `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:FromLocation` function. But when I get the current location, it is getting the new location. Was it meant to be like this or was this a bug? It currently doesn't affect my app, it's just hard to debug the location changes.

I'm using `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you have to set your current location in Xcode.
after that simulator is working:

```
locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:FromLocation method
```

In Xcode->Product->Debug->simulator Location
then set any one location as current.